# For each NAME, calculate the average SNOW for each month

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Show the specified columns and save it to a new file
col_list= ["STATION", "NAME", "DATE", "AWND", "SNOW"]
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', usecols=col_list)
df.to_csv('filteredData.csv')

df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE']).year

df2016 = df[(df.year==2016)]

df_2016 = df2016.groupby(['NAME', 'DATE'])['SNOW'].mean()
df_2016.to_csv('average2016.csv')
```

[image: This is what the excel file looks like]

1. How come my dates are not ordered correctly here? Row 12 should be on the top but it's on the bottom of May instead and same goes for row 25
2. The average of SNOW per  NAME/month is also not being displayed on my excel sheet. Why is that? Basically, I'm trying to calculate the average SNOW for May in ADA 0.7 SE, MI US. Then calculate the average SNOW for June in ADA 0.7 SE, MI US. etc..

I've spent all day and this is all I have got... Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

original data
https://gofile.io/?c=1gpbyT

Comment: Can you share an example of your starting CSV data to help with figuring out the missing `mean` values?

Comment: For question 1, it looks like dates are ordered alphabetically. If you want to order chronologically, the easiest way is to make alphabetical and chronological match, which you can do by using the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: I added a new screenshot with the code that I was trying to sort. I think some data for SNOW were supposed to be blank. I think I'm trying to add a new column with the calculations for the average SNOW in each month.

Comment: Please apply my example to your data. If it doesnt work let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

Data

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'directorywhere the data is\data.csv')
df
```

Working

```
 df.dtypes# Checking the datatype on each column

df.columns#listing columns

df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])#Converting date from object to a date format

df.set_index(df['DATE'], inplace=True)#Seeting the date as index

df['SNOW'].fillna(0)#filling all Not a Number values with zeros to make aggregation possible

df['SnowMean']=df.groupby([df.index.month, df.NAME])['SNOW'].transform('mean')#Groupby name, month and calculate the mean of snow. Store the result in anew column called df['SnowMean']
df
```

Checking

```
df.loc[:,['DATE','Month','SnowMean']]# Slice relevant columns to check
```

I realize you have multiple years. If you wanted mean per month in each year, again extract the year and add it in the groups to groupby as follows

```
df['SnowMeanPerYearPerMonth']=df.groupby([df.index.month,df.index.year,df.NAME])['SNOW'].transform('mean')
df
```

Check again

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',999)#diaplay upto 999 rows to check
df.loc[:,['DATE','Month','Year','SnowMean']]# Slice relevant columns to check
```

Comment: I tried using the code but I was getting exceptions. It's probably because I'm not doing it right.. I have just started learning Python so I don't understand some parts of your code. I did upload the original data. Greatly appreciated if you could try using mine. Thanks!

Comment: Let try what I have done. Happy to offer explanations

Comment: I noticed that you have "df" itself on some lines. What does that mean? When I run the code my data is not sorting by name first. How can I do that? I want to sort by name, then by date and calculate the mean of snow, and save that in two separate files, one for 2016 and one for 2017.

Comment: I use jupyter notebooks. In notebooks it is the equivalent of print(df). Did it woek?

Comment: Yess!! The code works and my data is sorting correctly now! How can I separate 2016 and 2017 into two different files?